# How to track devise login and logout with public_activity gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to track user login and logout activities. I am already using public_activity gem to track activities of other models in my application.

Here is an example of project tracking in my app: (project.rb)

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
      include PublicActivity::Model
      tracked
end
```

Now i want to track devise login and logout user activities via public_activity gem. How can i do that?

Comment: You need to manually add `create_activity` to devise SessionsController. Check docs about [customising controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

I found this hack in our `config/initializers`.

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user except: :fetch do |record, _warden, _options|
  record.create_activity(:signed_in, owner: record)
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |record, _warden, _options|
  record&.create_activity(:signed_out, owner: record)
end
```

Comment: Do you create any table for this to store this information? Is it possible to show the details in some view/page? Could you please share the project on github?

Comment: Sorry, private project. Information is stored in `activities` table, because `create_activity()` is from 'public_activity' gem.

Comment: Thanks not sure whether I understood it properly but if possible please share some dummy rails project on github when you get time. I will check how to access the activities table, also may try to get info using rails api. My project is rails 6, vuex, based